# Regex query where value is found find another value over multiple lines

Tags: javascript, regex

Could someone help me with writing a regex query for the following: Basically I have a few blocks of user permissions seperated by new lines. I am interested in finding the block that contains "admin" and if it does contain admin can we show only the username and enabled lines in full.

```
username,test
role,admin
enabled,true
last updated,01/01/2019

username,test2
role,user
enabled,true
last updated,01/02/2019

username,test5
role,user
enabled,true
last updated,01/03/2019
```

I have tried a lot of different varitation of regex and I can get it to work over and pull back several lines including the role but what I am after is, if the line contain the word admin, can I display specific lines.

```
(?(?=admin)enabled)
```

Comment: Why not read the data line by line (or even block by block) instead of parsing with regex?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a capturing group for the username and repeat matching the lines until encountering an empty line.

```
username,(\S+)\r?\nrole,admin(?:\r?\n(?!$).*)*
```

*About the pattern*

- `username,` Match literally
- `(\S+)` Capture the username in group 1 by matching 1+ times a non whitespace char
- `\r?\n` Match a newline
- `role,admin` Match literally
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\r?\n(?!$).*` Match a newline, assert what is directly on the right is not the end of the string. If that is the case, match the whole line
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K0CSHE/1)

```js
const regex = /username,(\S+)\r?\nrole,admin(?:\r?\n(?!$).*)*/gm;
const str = `username,test
role,admin
enabled,true
last updated,01/01/2019

username,test2
role,user
enabled,true
last updated,01/02/2019

username,test5
role,user
enabled,true
last updated,01/03/2019

`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  console.log(m[1])
}
```